# Rails Error on Windows: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick

I get this error when i ran my rails app on my Windows Localhost when I tried to upload an image.

I have a "product" model and I am using Mini_Magick with CarrierWave for uploading the product's image.

Image Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed

I have done the "bundle install" command after putting mini_magick gem in my gem-file and I have checked that Imagemagick is installed by running "convert" everything works fine... What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed GraphicsMagick on your machine?  You will need this installed locally if your doing any kind of image manipulation with your uploads, which it appears you are.

Downloads can be found here:
ftp://ftp.graphicsmagick.org/pub/GraphicsMagick/windows/

Comment: I have downloaded and installed GraphicsMagick on my machine but I still get the same error

Comment: This is a windows install correct? Also, did you ensure graphicsmagick is in your path? Usually, under `system properties > advanced > environment variables`

Comment: Yes it is and yes I have made sure that it is in the "Path" under environment variables ... but still it is giving me the same error how could I test if the graphicsmagick is working outside of the rails app?

Comment: You should be able to open up `command prompt` and type `gm` this should give you all the graphics magick commands. If you see that you know it's installed correctly.  Also, you can try these commands and you should see the gm logo. `gm convert logo: logo.miff` followed by
`gmdisplay logo.miff`

Answer (score 0):

Another advise: this error happened to me even after installing GraphicsMagick, I solved it by restarting visual studio code, which is the IDE I'm using. So, be ware of restarting the terminal you are using to run rails after installing GraphicsMagick